# presentViewController causing an error "view is not in the window hierarchy"

Tags: ios, presentviewcontroller

In the FirstViewController I have called a function in **viewdidload** and it is returning a value.

I want to present NextViewController if returned value is 1 else if return value in 0 I want some operation on FirstViewController.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ViewController *view1=[[ViewController alloc]init];
    int ret=[view1 getcustId];
    NSLog(@"the ret is %d",ret);
    if (ret==1)
    {
        Nextviewcontroller *nextview=[[Nextviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:nextview animated:YES completion:NULL];
        [super viewDidLoad];

    }
    else
    {
        im=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"591637.png"]];
        im.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,390,670);
        im.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        [self.view addSubview:im];
        [super viewDidLoad];

    }
}
```

But I am getting an error while presenting NextViewController.

`Warning: Attempt to present <Nextviewcontroller: 0x7f93b0e41780> on <ViewController: 0x7f93b0f3b630> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

how can I present NExtViewController from `viewDidLoad`? please help

Comment: Why can't you check this condition before pushing this view controller? If return value is 0 push this view controller else if value is 1 push Nextviewcontroller.

Comment: @WenchenHuang i am new to ios .can you please explain in code its already there ` Nextviewcontroller *nextview=[[Nextviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:nextview animated:YES completion:NULL];`

Comment: Also I don't think `ViewController *view1=[[ViewController alloc]init];
    int ret=[view1 getcustId];` this will give the desired result. Since `ViewController` is just initialised, so the value returned by `getcustId` method will always be same.

Comment: @divya try to debug your code... your code is correct but i think the value of ret is null. please check the value of Ret.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try calling `[super viewDidLoad]` first

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  ViewController *view1=[[ViewController alloc] init]; //this line
  int ret = [view1 getcustId]; //and this line doen't make sense
  NSLog(@"the ret is %d",ret);
  if (ret == 1) {
    Nextviewcontroller *nextview=[[Nextviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:nextview animated:YES completion:NULL];
  }
  else {
    im = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"591637.png"]];
    im.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 390, 670);
    im.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:im];
  }
}
```

Also show the code that has presented `ViewController`

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because of viewController presenting animation.You are trying to present a second view before finishing appearance of previous viewController.

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        ViewController *view1=[[ViewController alloc]init];
        int ret=[view1 getcustId];
        NSLog(@"the ret is %d",ret);
        if (ret==1)
        {
            Nextviewcontroller *nextview=[[Nextviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            [self presentViewController:nextview animated:YES completion:NULL];
            [super viewDidLoad];

        }
        else
        {
            im=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"591637.png"]];
            im.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,390,670);
            im.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            [self.view addSubview:im];
            [super viewDidLoad];

        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Write your code in **viewDidAppear**
2. Put nib name in initWithNibName instead of nil

   ```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

    {
   [super viewDidAppear:YES];

   ViewController *view1=[[ViewController alloc]init];
   int ret=[view1 getcustId];
   NSLog(@"the ret is %d",ret);
   if (ret==1)
   {
       Nextviewcontroller *nextview=[[Nextviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"Nextviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
       [self presentViewController:nextview animated:YES completion:NULL];
   }
   else
   {
       im=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"591637.png"]];
       im.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,390,670);
       im.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
       [self.view addSubview:im];
    }
   }
   ```